# What is the meaning of each section in this HTTP response?

Tags: django, http, server, client

[image]

I am curious about the meaning of this HTTP response. I understand that the method being used is `GET` and that the status code equals `200` which means success, but I don't understand the last part. Is it the data size?

```
<head>
<title>Django blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:ǓǏǏ"
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Django blog</a></h1>
</header>
<div>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at is the [Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format), and the last field is the size of the response in bytes.

Comment: Thank you ! I have another question, I am currently trying to develop a web application using Django but I am quite confused . Should develop a web application using REST API or use the traditional way ? Are there any backend development trends that I should know?